# Is there any way to show the group price instead of regular price all time?

Tags: magento-1.9, group-price

I am using Magento 1.9.3

For your convenience I am explaining with example:

Lets imagine two products.

Product1

> Regular Price : 50
>
> Group Price : 55

Product2

> Regular Price : 60
>
> Group Price : 55

When **Regular Price** is lower than **Group Price** it showing **Regular Price**.

Again when **Regular Price** is higher than **Group Price** it showing **Group Price**.

Always showing lower price.

For product1: 50 < 55 getting 50

For product2: 55 > 60 getting 55

But in both case I need to show the price: 55 (**Group Price**)

Can I do that?

Comment: I have the same problem but I couldn't solve it with your suggestion.
Can you please give me more details? step by step. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify **_applyGroupPrice** and **getBasePrice** method.

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php

Overwrite this class and remove min function from there.

**[Update]**

Overwrite config:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_type_price>SR_MagentoCommunity_Model_Product_Type_Price</product_type_price>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </models>
</global>
```

> app/code/local/SR/MagentoCommunity/Model/Product/Type/Price.php

```
<?php

class SR_MagentoCommunity_Model_Product_Type_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price
{
    public function getBasePrice($product, $qty = null)
    {
        $price = (float)$product->getPrice();
        $groupPrice = $product->getGroupPrice();
        if (is_numeric($groupPrice) && $groupPrice && ($groupPrice != $price)) {
            return $groupPrice;
        }

        return parent::getBasePrice($product, $qty);
    }

    /**
     * Get product group price
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @return float
     */
    public function getGroupPrice($product)
    {

        $groupPrices = $product->getData('group_price');
        if (is_null($groupPrices)) {
            $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('group_price');
            if ($attribute) {
                $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($product);
                $groupPrices = $product->getData('group_price');
            }
        }

        if (is_null($groupPrices) || !is_array($groupPrices)) {
            return $product->getPrice();
        }

        $customerGroup = $this->_getCustomerGroupId($product);

        $matchedPrice = 0;
        foreach ($groupPrices as $groupPrice) {
            if ($groupPrice['cust_group'] == $customerGroup) {
                $matchedPrice = $groupPrice['website_price'];
                break;
            }
        }

        return $matchedPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sohel bhai, Can you please tell me little bit details. I tried but couldn't solve by your suggestion.

Comment: @SASoibal I will post update today.

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: Wroked like a charm bro. Thanks a lot.